# is a there a free tool like Excelsior JET?

Tags: jakarta-ee, obfuscation

i tried Excelsior as an alternative to obfuscation i'm realy happy with the results but still i'm not sure if the company i work for would be interrested in Buying the product , so i'm wondering if there's a similar tool i can use for my Java EE web application .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: I work for the company that makes Excelsior JET.

I maintain a [list of Java code protection tools](https://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-obfuscators.html#products) as part of my article on that topic.

To the best of my knowledge, the only other ahead-of-time Java to native code compiler used to be GCJ (GNU Compiler for Java), which is now [history](http://tromey.com/blog/?p=911). I do not think it was ever capable of compiling Java EE apps anyway.

[GuardIT for Java](http://www.arxan.com/software-protection-products/java-GuardIt/index.php) targets in particular Java Web applications. It does not do native compilation, but has other interesting features such as tamper detection.

Answer (score -1):

Try JWrapper. And no its not just install packager. Plus they seem to allow far greater share of capabilities in their free edition which you can download right off the bat and even use commercially.

Comment: It's also not a compiler like Jet or GCJ, and has little relevance as an answer.